# How to add new "items" to a property of object in a JSON file? Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, json, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a JSON file like this, I'd like to add new item to the "Members" array in "Footballer" object. How can I do that in WP 8.1?

```
{
    "Groups": [
        {
            "UniqueId": "Footballer",
            "Region": "Europe",
            "Country": "England",
            "Members": [
                {
                    "UniqueId": "MANU",
                    "Name": "Rooney",
                    "JerseyNumber": "10",
                    "Position": "Forward"
                },
                {
                    "UniqueId": "CITY",
                    "Name": "Aguero",
                    "JerseyNumber": "16",
                    "Position": "Forward"
                },
                {
                    "UniqueId": "MANU",
                    "Name": "Nani",
                    "JerseyNumber": "7",
                    "Position": "Midfielder"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want the final result to look like this: [Please note that I want to add new item to "Members" property of "Footballer" object]

```
{
    "Groups": [
        {
            "UniqueId": "Footballer",
            "Region": "Europe",
            "Country": "England",
            "Members": [
                {
                    "UniqueId": "MANU",
                    "Name": "Rooney",
                    "JerseyNumber": "10",
                    "Position": "Forward"
                },
                {
                    "UniqueId": "CITY",
                    "Name": "Aguero",
                    "JerseyNumber": "16",
                    "Position": "Forward"
                },
                {
                    "UniqueId": "MANU",
                    "Name": "Nani",
                    "JerseyNumber": "7",
                    "Position": "Midfielder"
                },
                {
                    "UniqueId": "CITY",
                    "Name": "Yaya",
                    "JerseyNumber": "5",
                    "Position": "Midfielder"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So far I've been only able to add new object to the "Groups". Here is my code to do that and please help me modify this code to add new items to the "Members" property.

```
private async void Done_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("Data2.json");
    string jsonText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
    JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
    JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["Groups"].GetArray();

    JsonObject newGroupObject = new JsonObject();

    DateTime dt = (DateTime.Now).ToLocalTime();
    string date = dt.ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy'/'hh'/'mm'/'ss'/'tt");

    newGroupObject.Add("UniqueId", JsonValue.CreateStringValue(date));
    newGroupObject.Add("Name", JsonValue.CreateStringValue(nameBox.Text));
    newGroupObject.Add("JerseyNumber", JsonValue.CreateStringValue(jnoBox.Text));
    newGroupObject.Add("Position", JsonValue.CreateStringValue(posBox.Text));

    jsonArray.Add(newGroupObject);
    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, jsonObject.Stringify());
}
```

By using the above code I got the output as:

```
{
    "Groups": [
        {
            "UniqueId": "Footballer",
            "Region": "Europe",
            "Country": "England",
            "Members": [
                {
                    "UniqueId": "MANU",
                    "Name": "Rooney",
                    "JerseyNumber": "10",
                    "Position": "Forward"
                },
                {
                    "UniqueId": "CITY",
                    "Name": "Aguero",
                    "JerseyNumber": "16",
                    "Position": "Forward"
                },
                {
                    "UniqueId": "MANU",
                    "Name": "Nani",
                    "JerseyNumber": "7",
                    "Position": "Midfielder"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "UniqueId": "CITY",
            "Name": "Yaya",
            "JerseyNumber": "5",
            "Position": "Midfielder"
        }
    ]
}
```

I understand that I need to select the "Footballer" object from the "Groups" in JSON in order to add new items to "Members". I don't know the syntax for doing that. Thanks in advance for your valuable reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["Groups"].GetArray();
```

with

```
JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["Groups"].GetArray()[0].GetObject()["Members"].GetArray();
```

Comment: But it says I cannot implicitly convert type 'Windows.Data.Json.IJsonValue' to 'Windows.Data.Json.JsonObject'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: How can I delete an item and its properties from the json file using unique id of that item? I'm displaying an items' content in a page using unique id passed from the `ListView` page. How to delete that item from the property show page?

Comment: How can I delete a specific `Member` details if I only know the UniqueId of that Member?

Comment: sorry no idea on how to, you should post a new question perhaps someone can give you the rigth answer, good luck :) !